# ERROR: squareFeet cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

I am new to java programming and here is an issues that I have been stuck on.

```
  public static double Totalwallspace( int NumberofRooms )

  {

  double squarefeet;    
  double totalSquareFeet = 0;

  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  for( int currentRoom = 1; currentRoom <= NumberofRooms; currentRoom++){

  System.out.println("Please enter the square feet of the wall space in room: " + currentRoom);

  double squareFeet = scanner.nextDouble();

  scanner.close();

  totalSquareFeet = totalSquareFeet + sqaureFeet;

   }
   return totalSquareFeet;
}
```

Every time I try to compile it, just keeps giving me this message: squareFeet cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: `sqaureFeet` has a typo. `squareFeet` has a after u. **Remove `scanner.close();`**

Comment: You also have two different variables called `squareFeet` and `squarefeet`. That's confusing.

Comment: thank you! typo has been a pain for me so far!

Comment: Use an IDE. It helps with that a lot. Also with indentation.

Comment: Elliott - When i remove the scanner.close() it gives me a resource leak: 'scanner' is never closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `Scanner` should be closed and `try with resource` is the best way:

```
public static double Totalwallspace(int NumberofRooms) {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        double totalSquareFeet = 0;

        for (int currentRoom = 1; currentRoom <= NumberofRooms; currentRoom++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the square feet of the wall space in room: " + currentRoom);
            totalSquareFeet += scanner.nextDouble();
        }

        return totalSquareFeet;
    }
}
```